# Windows 10 WSL ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied Laravel

Tags: php, linux, laravel, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install Laravel on WSL. I have everything install so far but when I run the laravel command, I get a Permission Denied from ZipArchive. Is there a way around this?

Things I've tried:

- Directory is 777 -r
- Owner of directory errored with my user and www-data
- Making the file 777

  ```
  PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel_*.zip): failed to open    stream: Permission denied in /home/jeff/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 132
  PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/jeff/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 150
  PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/jeff/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 152
  Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www
  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
  Application ready! Build something amazing.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the `bash` as **Admin**. And use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel` to create laravel project than using the global `laravel installer`.

Do try **Laragon** if you want to develop in windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. I think I'm going to start with a vagrant box until there is a solution to running everything via WSL.